# Observing database object changes made from the background thread

Tags: android, android-room

I've met an issue with observing data in my app.

For the testing purposes, I have an activity with a single text view where I show the user's name. This is the code:

```
@Entity(tableName = "User")
data class User(
    var name: String,
    var surname: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val internalID: Long = 0)
```

in the dao I've got just one method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE surname LIKE :surname")
abstract suspend fun getUserForSurname(surname: String): User
```

in the activity onCreate's method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewmodel = model
    model.user.observe(this, Observer {
        binding.textTest.setText(it.name)
    })
}
```

and finally, view model:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val surname = "Doe"
    val user: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()
    private val userDao: UserDao =
        MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application).clientDao()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            user.value = userDao.getUserForSurname(surname)
        }
    }
}
```

That specific user's name is changed in the background thread. When I check for the value in db itself, the name is indeed different. After restarting activity, the text view is changed too. In other words: the db value is changed but the observer is never called. I know that I am asking for the value only once during viewmodel's init method and it may be a problem. Is it possible to see the actual change without restarting activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/#0)

Room exposes different wrappers around the returned Entities such as:

- RxJava
- Flow Coroutines
- LiveData

So you can changed your Dao as such:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE surname LIKE :surname")
abstract fun getUserForSurname(surname: String): LiveData<User>
```

The above means that any changes to the user entry will emit an observation to the listeners of the LiveData.

**ViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val surname = "Doe"
    lateinit val client: LiveData<User>
    private val userDao: UserDao =
        MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application).clientDao()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            user = userDao.getUserForSurname(surname)
        }
    }
}
```

Read more at: 
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

**Disclaimer:** Didn't test the above solution but it should give you an idea.

**EDIT:** Ideally **LiveData** should only be used in your view model as they were designed for such cases and not to observe DB transactions. I will suggest to replace the Dao's with Coroutine's Flow and use the [extension](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata) to convert to LiveData.

Comment: after changing metod return type to dao I got this error `Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`

Comment: LiveData as return type apply only for Lists, doesn't it?

Comment: You should remove suspend.

Comment: Thanks, it works and thanks for your edit tip also, it will be useful :)